# PHP file with JavaScript Extjs

Tags: php, javascript, extjs, syntax-error, xmlexception

A noob question here, by a novice programmer.

I am trying to do a javascript inside a .php file, in my index I included this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/basic.php"></script>
```

And in my basic.php:

```
<?php Header("content-type: text/javascript"); ?>
<script>
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
        enabled: true,
        disableCaching: false,
        paths: {
            "Extensible": "/js/extensible/src",
            "Schedule.Calendar.data": "/js/data",
            "Schedule.Calendar.listeners":"/js/listeners",
            "Schedule.Calendar.override":"/js/override",
            "Schedule.Calendar.panels": "/js/panels"
        }
    });
</script>
```

And it keeps sending an error saying:

> SyntaxError: missing } in XML expression

Comment: Why do you want it to be php, not static js?

Comment: because i want to add a symfony function inside a listener. I dont know if it works though, wanna try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `basic.php` file should only be outputting pure JavaScript. The `<script>` tags are HTML and are not needed.

Comment: It worked. But, I cannot add or execute php stuff on the middle of javascript. Inserting "<?php ....some stuff... ?>" it returns an error.

Comment: That should work. What is the error, and can you provide some example code for what you tried?